# Gnome VNC session not displaying correctly -- defaults to gnome-classic

Tags: gnome, vnc, tightvncserver

I'm trying to set up a VNC server in Ubuntu 22.04 using tightvnc. I pretty much have it working, except the gnome session is not displaying correctly. It looks like this:

[image]

which is sort of like gnome classic, but without the desktop background, so clearly things are not fully loading.

Here's my ~/.vnc/xstartup file:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh
autocutsel -fork
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

I've also tried another version which basically looks the same:

```
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

And here's my systemd service:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service 

[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
Group=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/user

PIDFile=/home/user/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My .Xresources file is empty (but exists).

And lastly, the current status of the service kicks up a couple of errors, but I can't figure out what they mean or how to debug them:

```
● vncserver@1.service - Start TightVNC server at startup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-14 18:53:37 CET; 19min ago
    Process: 28167 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 (code=exited, status=2)
    Process: 28171 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost :1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 28182 (Xtightvnc)
      Tasks: 155 (limit: 629145)
     Memory: 257.2M
        CPU: 32.435s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@1.service
             ├─28182 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop X -auth /home/user/.Xauthority -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -fp /usr/share/font>
             ├─28269 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug
             ├─28272 dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug
             ├─28273 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
             ├─28283 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
             ├─28293 gnome-flashback
             ├─28294 /usr/libexec/gnome-flashback-clipboard
             ├─28297 /usr/libexec/gnome-flashback-media-keys
             ├─28298 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-immediately
             ├─28304 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/home/user/.cache/at-spi/bus_1
             ├─28308 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
             ├─28324 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
             ├─28324 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
             ├─28332 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /home/user/.cache/gvfs -f
             ├─28348 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
             ├─28357 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
             ├─28362 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
             ├─28367 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
             ├─28373 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
             ├─28377 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
             ├─28385 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
             ├─28390 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
             ├─28395 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
             ├─28397 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
             ├─28398 /usr/libexec/ibus-extension-gtk3
             ├─28402 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
             ├─28404 /usr/libexec/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
             ├─28408 metacity
             ├─28411 /usr/libexec/ibus-portal
             ├─28421 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
             ├─28434 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.23 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
             ├─28444 gnome-panel
             ├─28445 /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simple
             ├─28459 /usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
             ├─28460 nm-applet
             ├─28466 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
             ├─28467 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3
             ├─28484 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
             ├─28498 /usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
             ├─28564 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
             ├─28576 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
             ├─28591 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
             ├─30350 update-notifier
             └─30411 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk

Dez 14 18:54:39 BF1370032 update-notifier.desktop[30399]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
Dez 14 18:54:39 BF1370032 update-notifier.desktop[30399]: This incident has been reported.
Dez 14 18:54:41 BF1370032 metacity.desktop[28408]: Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Dez 14 18:55:37 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): Starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App58
Dez 14 18:55:37 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: starting org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor.desktop: command=/usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor startup-id=1>
Dez 14 18:55:37 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: GnomeDesktop-DEBUG(+): Not systemd managed, will not move PID 30446 into transient scope
Dez 14 18:55:37 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: started pid:30446
Dez 14 18:57:37 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: (pid:30446) done (status:0)
Dez 14 19:05:36 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): GsmSystemd: received logind signal: SessionNew
Dez 14 19:05:36 BF1370032 gnome-session-binary[28269]: DEBUG(+): GsmSystemd: ignoring SessionNew signal
```

Any thoughts on how to make the gnome session look like the default gnome environment? Do I just need to install some additional extensions or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I am on the same boat.  Did you figure?

Comment: Nope, after a ton of trouble shooting it just seems that the vncserver service running a virtual desktop can't handle 3d acceleration. I was able to get it to work with KDE, if that's useful, but I ended up just going back to x11vnc to reveal the current active desktop. Works fine for a single user and with a monitor, but wouldn't work for multiple users or a headless box.